# Images as Planes - Error/Blank - Blender 2.8

Tags: image

Whenever I add images as plane to Blender 2.8, it comes up as grey/blank like this.

I want to use as a reference image to start modelling, but I cannot see the actual image.

If I drag the image in, as normal - not as plane. I can see the picture fine. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press 'z' and choose LookDev or change viewport shading to Lighting: Studio/Flat and Color: Texture.

[image]

Comment: Additional Info: Texture option only show the last selected (active) texture in the material(shader) node. If the texture in view port is not what you want, try to enter shader editor and select a texture you want to display.